# Executing multiple commands( or from a shell script) in a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm writing a shell script which needs to login into the pod and execute a series of commands in a kubernetes pod.

Below is my sample_script.sh:

```
kubectl exec octavia-api-worker-pod-test -c octavia-api bash
unset http_proxy https_proxy
mv /usr/local/etc/octavia/octavia.conf /usr/local/etc/octavia/octavia.conf-orig
/usr/local/bin/octavia-db-manage --config-file /usr/local/etc/octavia/octavia.conf upgrade head
```

After running this script, I'm not getting any output.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Not really descriptive: What output would you expect?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Are you running all these commands as a single line command? First of all, there's no `;` or `&&` between those commands. So if you paste it as a multi-line script to your terminal, likely it will get executed locally.

Second, to tell bash to execute something, you need: `bash -c "command"`.

Try running this:

```
$ kubectl exec POD_NAME -- bash -c "date && echo 1"

Wed Apr 19 19:29:25 UTC 2017
1
```

You can make it multiline like this:

```
$ kubectl exec POD_NAME -- bash -c "date && \
      echo 1 && \
      echo 2"
```

Comment: What does '--' do in this case? Why is it needed?

Comment: The double dash symbol "--" is used to separate the arguments you want to pass to the command from the kubectl arguments

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't seen such separator for docker. Does it exist there as well ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 No. In `docker run` command, any positional argument that comes after the `[image]` argument is considered to be `CMD` arguments. And you can pass an `--entrypoint=[program]` option before the `[image]`. e.g. `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=sleep busybox 9999` runs `sleep 9999`

Answer (score 10):

The following should work

> `kubectl -it exec podname -- bash -c "ls && ls"`

```
bin   dev   etc   home  proc  root  run   sys   tmp   usr   var bin  
dev   etc   home  proc  root  run   sys   tmp   usr   var
```

If above command doesn't work then try too replace `bash` with one of the following `/bin/bash`, `sh` or `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 5):

Posting here because google search still brings you to this post...

I'd like to throw out using a HEREDOC as an additional possibility.

```
kubectl exec -i --tty=false PODNAME -- bash << EOF
echo "insert all your commands here."
echo "this subprocess will even pickup any variables you have in"
echo "the shell script that is calling this"
EOF
```

Comment: It should be --tty=false.

Answer (score 4):

> -t
>    can solve your task

For example, I run here few cmd:

```
kubectl get pods |grep nginx|cut -f1 -d\  |\
while read pod; \
 do echo "$pod writing:";\
  kubectl exec -t $pod -- bash -c \
   "dd if=/dev/zero of=/feeds/test.bin bs=260K count=4 2>&1|\
    grep copi |cut -d, -f4; \
    a=$SECONDS; echo -ne 'reading:'; cat /feeds/test.bin >/dev/null ; \
    let a=SECONDS-a ; \
    echo $a sec"
done
```

p.s. your example will be:

```
kubectl exec -t octavia-api-worker-pod-test -c octavia-api -- bash -c "unset http_proxy https_proxy ; mv /usr/local/etc/octavia/octavia.conf /usr/local/etc/octavia/octavia.conf-orig ; /usr/local/bin/octavia-db-manage --config-file /usr/local/etc/octavia/octavia.conf ; upgrade ; head"
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. -t has certain output characters like \r you should probably not use in your scripts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55034214/why-do-docker-run-t-outputs-include-r-in-the-command-output