# Kubectl exec command to write contents to a file in the pod

Tags: kubernetes, exec, kubectl

I am trying below command

```
kubectl exec -it sss-pod-four  echo "hi" >> /mnt/sss/testnew.txt
```

But it throws error

```
-bash: /mnt/sss/testnew.txt: No such file or directory
```

What is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499313/executing-multiple-commands-or-from-a-shell-script-in-a-kubernetes-pod)   and below command works now

```
 kubectl exec -it sss-pod-four  -- bash -c "echo hi > /mnt/sss/testnew.txt"
```

Comment: Isn't the `-it` on this command redundant?

Comment: yup.. dont need -it.

Comment: I tried to copy a file one directory to root directory 
kubectl exec -it podname -- bash -c  "move c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\westus\log4net.config  c:\inetpub\wwwroot" - buts its not working