# How do I pass multiple arguments to a shell script into `kubectl exec`?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl, positional-parameter

Consider the following shell script, where `POD` is set to the name of a K8 pod.

```
kubectl exec -it $POD -c messenger -- bash -c "echo '$@'"
```

When I run this script with one argument, it works fine.

```
hq6:bot hqin$ ./Test.sh  x
x
```

When I run it with two arguments, it blows up.

```
hq6:bot hqin$ ./Test.sh  x y
y': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
y': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I suspect that something is wrong with how the arguments are passed.

**How might I fix this so that arguments are expanded literally by my shell and then passed in as literals to the `bash` running in `kubectl exec`?**

Note that removing the single quotes results in an output of `x` only.
Note also that I need the `bash -c` so I can eventually pass in file redirection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49189635/391161.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to work around this with the following solution:

```
kubectl exec -it $POD -c messenger -- bash -c "echo $*"
```

This appears to have the additional benefit that I can do internal redirects.

```
./Test.sh x y '> /tmp/X'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want something like this:

```
kubectl exec POD -c CONTAINER -- sh -c 'echo "$@"' -- "$@"
```

With this syntax, the command we're running inside the container is `echo "$@"`. We then take the local value of `"$@"` and pass that as parameters to the remote shell, thus setting `$@` in the remote shell.

On my local system:

```
bash-5.0$ ./Test.sh hello
hello
bash-5.0$ ./Test.sh hello world
hello world
```