# Execute bash command in pod with kubectl?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

My question is simple.

How to execute a bash command in the pod? I want to do everything with a single bash command.

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl exec -it --namespace="tools" mongo-pod --bash -c "mongo"
Error: unknown flag: --bash
```

So, the command is simply ignored.

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl exec -it --namespace="tools" mongo-pod bash -c "mongo"
root@mongo-deployment-78c87cb84-jkgxx:/#
```

Or so.

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl exec -it --namespace="tools" mongo-pod bash mongo
Defaulting container name to mongo.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/mongo-deployment-78c87cb84-jkgxx -n tools' to see all of the containers in this pod.
/usr/bin/mongo: /usr/bin/mongo: cannot execute binary file
command terminated with exit code 126
```

If it's just a bash, it certainly works. But I want to jump into the mongo shell immediatelly.

I found a solution, but it does not work. Tell me if this is possible now?
[Executing multiple commands( or from a shell script) in a kubernetes pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499313/executing-multiple-commands-or-from-a-shell-script-in-a-kubernetes-pod)

Thanks.

Comment: `bash -c` does not add anything useful here.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

The double dash symbol "--" is used to separate the command you want to run inside the container from the kubectl arguments.
So the correct way is:

```
kubectl exec -it --namespace=tools mongo-pod -- bash -c "mongo"
```

You forgot a space between "--" and "bash".

To execute multiple commands you may want:

- to create a script and mount it as a volume in your pod and execute it
- to launch a side container with the script and run it

Comment: >"to create a script and mount it as a volume in your pod and execute it" - Given a script, how can I mount it to a Pod as a volume using kebectl? It's easy with docker, but I do not know how to do that with Kubernetes.

Comment: Mount the volume containing the script and then call it from inside your container. For example in your container you call /volume/script.sh and in kubernetes you mount your volume and give /volume as mount folder.

Comment: I guess my main problem is creating the volume containing the script. With Docker it's trivial to mount some part of host filesystem to the container. With multi-node Kubernetes cluster, I'm at loss.

Comment: Take a look here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/

Comment: Does it mean that the only way to create a kubernetes volume from a local file is to upload the file to a web server, then create a pod which would download the file to the volume? I'm just trying to understand whether I'm just stupid or is the design really that ...inconvenient.

Comment: I might be a bit late to the party here, but I've just come across this answer - you could create the script in a ConfigMap and mount the config map as a volume in the container?

Answer (score 29):

I use something like this to get into the pod's shell:

```
    kubectl exec -it --namespace develop pod-name bash
```

then you can execute the command you want within the pod (e.g. ping)

```
    ping www.google.com
```

then you can see your ping log and voila ... enjoy it :D

Comment: It's not executing any command on the pod shell. It is just logging on to the pod shell.

Comment: @Anthony , Nicola, it seems kubectl exec requires container name (irrespective of we specified or not) . Isnt there a way to just connect the pod ( and not the container) ?

Comment: @Vishal786btc your perception is very subjective taking into account that the post does not indicate executing a command without having to enter the pod, so some will want to enter or not inside the pod to execute a command.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was the right command (and order of parameters) to open a pod shell:

```
kubectl -n <namepace> exec -it <pod> -- /bin/sh
```

*Note*: Using `/bin/bash` caused this error:

> error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container:
> failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "": OCI runtime exec
> failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec:
> "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown

So make sure you're using `/bin/sh` to avoid unwanted errors.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly run below one liner with your custom commands for Execute bash command in pod with kubectl purpose

```
kubectl exec -it  nginx-pod  -- bash -c "ls;pwd;echo hello;uname -r;cat /etc/*se"
```

Answer (score 0):

- Case 1: For one container in the pod, you could directly use

  `kubectl exec -it -n NAMESPACE pod-name -- /bin/bash`

  or

  `kubectl exec -it -n NAMESPACE pod-name -- /bin/sh`

  it depended on the type of shell command used in your pod.
- Case 2: There is more than one container in the Pod, the additional `-c` could be used to figure out this container.

  `kubectl exec -it -n NAMESPACE pod-name -c container-name -- /bin/bash`
- Case 3: There is NO shell in your container image, like `cluster autoscaler`. One option is to run a shell in this container through [`ephemeral containers`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/) and `kubectl debug`. **Note**: Ephemeral container support went into beta in Kubernetes **1.23**.

  `kubectl debug -n NAMESPACE -it pod-name --image=ubuntu`