# How to execute a mq script file in a Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, ibm-mq, kubernetes-pod

I have a file .mqsc with a commands for create queues(ibm mq).
How to run a script by kubectl?
`kubectl exec -n test -it mq-0 -- /bin/bash -f create_queues.mqsc` doesn't work.
log:

> /bin/bash: create_queues.mqsc: No such file or directory command terminated with exit code 127

Comment: Does this help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247619/execute-bash-command-in-pod-with-kubectl

Comment: @rock'nrolla no

Comment: Is `create_queues.mqsc` file at one of locations specified as `$PATH` ?

Comment: Can you check what your working directory is, e.g. with `kubectl directory exec -n test -it mq-0 -- pwd` and where is the file `create_queues.mqsc` ?

Comment: Just specify the full path and filename.  i.e. `/some/path/to/create_queues.mqsc`

Comment: MQSC commands need to be piped into the `runmqsc` command and unless you only have one queue manager in the container and it is set at the default you will also need to specify the queue manager name as on arg to `runmqsc` that you want the commands to apply to.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your script is not under the "/" directory in docker.  You need to find whole path after that you need to execute script