# Why do "docker run -t" outputs include \r in the command output?

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker client Version:           18.09.2.

When I run start a container interactively and run a `date` command, then pipe its output to `hexdump` for inspection, I'm seeing a trailing `\n` as expected:

```
$ docker run --rm -i -t alpine
/ # date | hexdump -c
0000000   T   h   u       M   a   r           7       0   0   :   1   5
0000010   :   0   6       U   T   C       2   0   1   9  \n
000001d
```

However, when I pass the `date` command as an entrypoint directly and run the container, I get a `\r` `\n` every time there's a new line in the output.

```
$ docker run --rm -i -t --entrypoint=date alpine | hexdump -c
0000000   T   h   u       M   a   r           7       0   0   :   1   6
0000010   :   1   9       U   T   C       2   0   1   9  \r  \n
000001e
```

This is weird.

It totally doesn't happen when I omit `-t` (not allocating any TTY):

```
docker run --rm -i --entrypoint=date alpine | hexdump -c
0000000   T   h   u       M   a   r           7       0   0   :   1   7
0000010   :   3   0       U   T   C       2   0   1   9  \n
000001d
```

What's happening here?

This sounds dangerous, as I use `docker run` command in my scripts, and if I forget to omit `-t` from my scripts, the output I'll collect from `docker run` command will have **invisible**/non-printible `\r` characters which can cause all sorts of issues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

tldr; This is a `tty` default behaviour and unrelated to docker. Per the [ticket filed on github about your exact issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8513).

---

Quoting the relevant comments in that ticket:

> Looks like this is indeed TTY by default translates newlines to CRLF

```
$ docker run -t --rm debian sh -c "echo -n '\n'" | od -c
0000000   \r  \n
0000002
```

> disabling "translate newline to carriage return-newline" with stty -onlcr correctly gives;

```
$ docker run -t --rm debian sh -c "stty -onlcr && echo -n '\n'" | od -c
0000000   \n
0000001
```

> Default TTY options seem to be set by the kernel ... On my linux host it contains:

```
/*
 * Defaults on "first" open.
 */
#define TTYDEF_IFLAG    (BRKINT | ISTRIP | ICRNL | IMAXBEL | IXON | IXANY)
#define TTYDEF_OFLAG    (OPOST | ONLCR | XTABS)
#define TTYDEF_LFLAG    (ECHO | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN | ECHOE|ECHOKE|ECHOCTL)
#define TTYDEF_CFLAG    (CREAD | CS7 | PARENB | HUPCL)
#define TTYDEF_SPEED    (B9600)
```

> `ONLCR` is indeed there.

When we go looking at the [`ONLCR` flag documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty), we can see that:

> [-]onlcr: translate newline to carriage return-newline

To again quote the [github ticket](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8513#issuecomment-216269864):

> Moral of the story, don't use -t unless you want a TTY.
>   TTY line endings are CRLF, this is not Docker's doing.